# How to access a dictionary value with a list index number in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

Hey guys here´s my problem.

Lets say I have two dictionaries and a list containing both dictionaries:

```
a={1:"hello",2:"goodbye"}
b={1:"Hi",2:"Farewell"}
list1=[a,b]
```

Now, if I iterate over the entire list like this, everything works fine:

```
for e in list1:
    print(e[1])
```

However, whenever I try to iterate over the list by using the list index number, python throws an error message ("TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'")

```
for e in list1[0]:
    print(e[1])
```

Could someone explain how I can access the dictionary value of a certain item in a list with a list index number?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You are trying to ask : Why is `for e in a: print(e[1])` not working given a dictionary `a`. The answer is when you iterate in a dict of `a` like that, your `e`s are the keys. In first iteration - `e` is 1, second, `e` is 2. Now, how can you query `e[1]` on an integer? You can't. What you need to clarify to yourself is: How to iterate inside a dict as key-value pairs. You'll figure out the problem that way easily.

Comment: A good practice is: Right after you execute the `for e in list1[0]:` part, you have an `e` in your hand. Always print that object in the first line of the loop. That way, before attempting to subscript it like `e[1]`, you can see what you are working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that `list1[0]` is a dictionary, and when using the way you are doing in a for loop, it'l iterate over the keys of that dictionary

so in your case, for the first iteration the `e` variable is of type `int` with the value 1, in the second iteration it has the value `2`.

so if you want to iterate over the keys, and values of a dictionary you should use

```
for key, val in list1[0].items():
    print('key: {}, value {}'.format(key, val))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
a = {1: "hello", 2: "goodbye"}
b = {1: "Hi", 2: "Farewell"}
list1 = [a, b]

for index, dict_data in enumerate(list1):
    print(index)
    print(dict_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the .get method like this:

```
for d in list1:
    for i in d:
        print(d.get(i))
```

maybe this can help you

Answer (score 0):

`list1[0]` is a `dict`. using `for ... in ...` on a `dict` iterates the keys, and your keys are ints.

try:

```
for e in list1[0]:
    print(e)
    print(list1[0][e])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

`for e in list1[0]:
    print(e)`

Comment: but this way will print all the dictionary in array

Answer (score -1):

Dictionary entries aren't stored in a given order, so the output won't be what you expect. However, you can do `next(e.values())`.

Comment: Actually starting with Python 3.7 they are guaranteed to be in order

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! What's the ordering?

Comment: The order in which they were inserted in